# How do I convert a PowerBI query into a flat file?

Tags: csv, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, flat-file

I am working on a huge file in PowerBI.  I had to shut down everything on my system to merge data to my main query file from an even bigger file.  Now I want to manipulate the data in the merged file, but it seems to be re-opening the query when I edit.  Is there a way I can turn my main file into a flat data file, so it does not perform background updates on the queries?

In Excel I would just copy the data set and paste it as text without any formulae.  But the PowerBI data is way too big for this.  9 million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use DaxStudio an convert it to a csv file. I don't know how it performs with 9 mio rows.
in DaxStudio the output of your DAX code has to be a table (compared to a single value in a PowerBI measure).
so if all your data is in one table you can just write

```
Evaluate 
   [table name]
```

then go to Advance-> export data

Comment: I have never used DAX studio. I will have a look at it thanks.

Comment: I tried downloading DAX studio but I think my firewall does not like it.  I got a version installed but it cannot read .pbix files

Comment: This is working for me.  Took a bit of familiarization with Dax Studio but this helped: https://xxlbi.com/blog/dax-studio-export-all-data/